# Second round of applications at CERN

Tags: postdocs, job-search, physics

I have applied for a CERN postdoc theory fellowship. After the 21st, I got no response (unlike many other places, CERN sends an email even in case of rejecting the application) and decided to ask a person from the theory department what my status was. I got the reply stating that at the 1st round, they can't offer me a position. Probably (correct me if I am wrong), it means that there may be a chance for me if someone from the first round declines the offer later (before the 15th of February). Then, I asked about my position in the queue for the second round but did not get an answer (yet).

Does anyone know about these rounds, in particular, if there is such a thing as a "queue" for each subsequent round?

Comment: They might think it improper to give "position in the queue" information. And, any queue might not be cast in stone with reevaluations possible, though I don't know CERN's policies.

Comment: The answer shouldn't change your next steps, which involve applying for other positions and waiting.

Comment: @BryanKrause : I have to inform my current place whether I want to extend my current postdoc with an extra year. On the other hand, CERN is a preferable place for me. It is therefore very important to me to know this detail.

Comment: Knowing where you are in the queue won't tell you if you're hired or not until you are, so you need a contingency either way.

Comment: @BryanKrause : I know that 2-3 people reject the offer every year, so if I were 1st-2nd, there is a chance, while if 3rd-4th, it would be hopeless. So knowing the order is very important to make a realistic plan.

Comment: If the average is 2-3 that reject, you can be sure that the confidence interval includes 0.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Just because the information is important to you does not mean that you can obtain it.